# Wordpress 3.8 Subdomain redirects every time to the Login Page and Permalinks throw 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

As you can see, I have two problems. But both are equally important for me.

**What i want:**

- **1.** I want to redirect my domain "www.domain.de/blog" to "blog.domain.de".
- **2.** I want to enable the "pretty" Permalinks over the Worpress Admin Panel.

**Background Information:**

- I have my own Server with root Rights, Ubuntu and full Access.
- Domain from united-domains on the Folder /var/www/domain.de.
- My Subdomain redirects to "var/www/domain.de/blog/current"
- Wordpress is in the folder "var/www/domain.de/blog/current"
- My Wordpress is a single Blog, no Multisite!
- My Document root points to "var/www/domain.de"

**1. Case:**

I created the subdomain "blog.domain.de" in united-domains and redirect to the folder /var/www/domain.de/blog. In WordPress I have set the two URL fields on blog.domain.de.

And here is the first problem. I can visit the site with the url blog.domain.de, but when I want to login via wp-login, then the URL makes nothing and I get a complete white Page. When I now go back to the blog.domain.de, than I am logged in, but every step who wants a Login will redirect to the wp-login site and I am no longer logged in.

I have cleared the cache and google the problem, but all solutions are for Multisites and not working with my Wordpress.

**2. Case:**

When I enable the Permalinks on the Wordpress Settings and go to a single Post, it's return a 404 Error. 
Wordpress has acces to the .htaccess file (chmod 0777 rights) and write the Rewrite Rule like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Problem solved for Case 1 AND 2**

Okay, I asked the Question to the host of my Server, too. And they have a Web Application Firewall before my Server, which don't allow Subdomains. My host have added the subdomains to the firewall, and now all is working like a charm. :)

Thanks for the special help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On point 2:**

Can you please try adjusting:

```
RewriteBase /domain.de/blog/current/
```

to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Also I usually have the following path in the last rewrite line (instead of the full path, specified in yours: /domain.de/blog/current/index.php):

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

These both adjustments could set the proper .htaccess rewrite rules and that could fix the point 1 issue.

**On point 1:**

If issue 1 is not fixed yet, you should try debugging to find the actual error you are experiencing. You should start by adding the following setting in the wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Let me know the results and I'll try to help further (if needed).

Comment: **On Point 2:** 
It's not working, the same problem. The .htaccess file is in the same Folder as the wp-config file, so that Wordpress can write in the file. I hope this is right?! 

**On Point 1**
I have added the line in the wp-config file, what will WP now do? Is there any log file I have to watch? Sorry, I new to Wordpress. I come from Rails, and here I am a Beginner, too ^^

Comment: It seems hard to answer your questions, because additinal feedback from tests is needed. So I could recommend you to start with: find the exact error when you see the blank page by deguggind the Wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
The goal of the added WP_DEBUG setting is to see the error on the screen, but you should also have it appended to the server's error_log file.

You could check the error_log on your server (the error should be written there), but I couldn't help much in this one as I usually use CPanel (not VPS) and have the error_log in the panel.

Comment: On point 2: Does your "Document root" of the subdomain points to /var/www/domain.de/blog and your wordpress is placed into a folder /current (here are wp-config and .htaccess)? If this is the case, then you could check "running wordpress from its own directory": http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory and also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress (different cases explained)

Let us know if you have additional information - edit your question above and include the new data.

Comment: My log under apache2/error.log says that my "/article-time.de/blog/current/.htaccess: Options not allowed here" and my "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible". I think, my Apache2 Setup is not right.

Comment: See above under "Background Information:" over my Document root.

Comment: OK, that's a progress. Check the following, please:
1. Your domain's "Document root" points to "var/www/domain.de"? Yes-No?
2. Your subdomain's "Document root" points to "var/www/domain.de/blog/current" or "var/www/domain.de/blog"? (which one)
3. The WP now is within: "var/www/domain.de/blog/current".

This will help me to check what we are going to do:
1. move the WP from /blog to subdomain's "/" only;
2. move the WP from /blog to subdomain's "/" + giving it its own directory.
Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved for Case 1 AND 2

Okay, I asked the Question to the host of my Server, too. And they have a Web Application Firewall before my Server, which don't allow Subdomains. My host have added the subdomains to the firewall, and now all is working like a charm. :)

Thanks for the special help!

Comment: I'm glad it works now! :-) Could you please let me know - did you changed the .htaccess, compared to your initial post (and if yes, you can update your question and post the working changes)? The most important reason is to check for myself if the RewriteBase was wrong or not, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you was right! When everything is set up right, than the Wordpress will automatically write the .htaccess the way you answer.

Comment: If your .htaccess is fixed the way described in my answer, then you can mark it as 'accepted'. If it's not the case, then I don't know what to do, I joined the community today and I'm not very experienced on this topic... :-) Just a reminder: remove (or comment) the WP_DEBUG setting when the site is live!